# Singnals from detached QProcess

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4

I am trying to start detached QProcess and do something on it's finish. For example putty tunneling. I have class to keep info about both processes:

```
   class TunnelInfo(object):
    def __init__(self,tunnelprocess,mainprocess):
        self.tp=tunnelprocess
        self.mp=mainprocess
        print "init"
        self.mp.finished.connect(self.killTunnel)
    def killTunnel(self,a,b): 
        print "killing tunnel"
        print self.tp
        self.tp.kill()
```

Then I am trying to execute putty:

```
prcs=QtCore.QProcess(self.parent)
prcs.startDetached(self.conf.putty_path, ['-pw',d.password,'-l',d.login,d.ip])
ti=self.TunnelInfo(tp,prcs)
```

Putty starts ok but signal is not received... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've found somewhere that startDetached is fire and forget. I have solved it with QThread:

```
  class ConnectionThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self,parent,command,commandargs,tunnelthread=None):
       super(ConnectionThread,self).__init__(parent.parent)
       self.command=command
       self.commandargs=commandargs
       self.tunnelthread=tunnelthread
       self.parent=parent
       print command,commandargs
       self.finished.connect(self.killtunnel)
    def run(self):
       self.process=QtCore.QProcess()
       self.process.start(self.command,self.commandargs)
       self.process.waitForFinished(msecs=3000000)
    def killtunnel(self):
       if self.tunnelthread is not None:
          self.tunnelthread.process.kill()
          self.tunnelthread.exit(0)
          print "killed!"
```